# Cannot compare two strings using <

Tags: java, android

My code reads a number ("`4`") from a `.txt` file, in sd card, then It is supposed to compare this number against "`5`". but It is not letting me, It says 
"*operator '<' cannot be applied to java.lang.stringbuilder*"

this is how I read-

```
  StringBuilder serverApkVersion = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(VerFileDirectory));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                serverApkVersion.append(line);
                serverApkVersion.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "error reading ver file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

this is how I compare-

```
   if (serverApkVersion > 5) {
```

PS:: I have tried this -

`int serverApkVersion = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(serverVersion));`

but it force closes, log says `"invalid int "5" "`

Comment: what you want to compare?

Comment: `"4"` is a string, not a number.

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)

Comment: I recommend you learning at least Java basics before doing something. If you did that, you'd knwo that you can't compare string and integer. You have to convert string to int first.

Comment: @JineshFrancis - Have you tried that?  Hint: ... try your "solutions" before you post them.

Answer (score 0):

You want to compare an Integer with an Integer so

```
if (Integer.valueOf (serverApkVersion.toString ()) > 5)
```